# Callable / Runnable Controller methods: What's the point?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous

In Spring, you can let controllers return a Callable instead of T, which will immediately release the request processing thread and compute the result in a MvcAsync Thread managed by the WebAsyncManager. You just need to wrap the controller method content in a `return () -> {... return result; };`. Very easy!

**But what is the point?** What is the difference between
**a) having 500 request processing threads** and letting them do all the work and
**b) having just a few request processing threads and executing all requests in Callables with a concurrencyLimit of 500**?

The second option b) actually looks worse to me, since there is overhead involved in managing the whole MvcAsync magic.

I get how you can harvest @Async methods to execute two methods at once and return a result once both finished, but I obviously didn't understand Callable controller methods.

Comment: That thread processing your request would wait while the response is processed, but if you return a Callable or a CompletableFuture, the thread is returned to the tread pool and be used to attend other clients in the meantime which would increase your throughput.

Comment: Second option might be helpfull when time-consuming requests occur.For example income request requires slow db selects or additional requests to external APIs. In highload web applications all requests usually handle in async and non-blocking modes. Sometimes it is only one choice to keep high concurrency pressure without additional horizontal scaling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have a Tomcat server that has 10 threads listening for client requests. If you have a client that invokes an endpoint that takes 5 seconds to respond, that client holds that thread for those 5 seconds. Add a few concurrent clients and you will soon run out of threads during those 5 seconds.

The situation is even worse, because during most of those 5 seconds your request is doing mostly I/O, which means you just block your thread to do nothing but waiting.

So, the ability of Spring to use Callable, CompletableFuture or ListenableFuture as the return types of controllers is precisely to allow programmers to overcome this kind of problem to a certain extend.

Fundamentally, just returning one of these types is only going to release the Web Server thread making it available to be used by another client. So you get to attend more clients in the same amount of time, However that, by itself, may not be enough to implement a non-blocking IO (aka NIO) API.

Most of these features come from the core functionality offered by Servlet API and Servlet Async IO, which Spring should probably use under the hood. You may want to take a look at the following interesting videos that helped me understand this from the ground up:

- [Scale your Web Applications with Servlet 3.1 Async I/O, Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1VjAHTxCBo&index=2&list=PL1ENklHO5h7M2Ez8xir2k4bVqge0kz4rk)
- [Scale your Web Applications with Servlet 3.1 Async I/O, Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUPSMRVT6VI&index=3&list=PL1ENklHO5h7M2Ez8xir2k4bVqge0kz4rk)
- [Into the Wild with Servlet Async IO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGXsnB2S_vc&index=1&list=PL1ENklHO5h7M2Ez8xir2k4bVqge0kz4rk)

Those videos explain the idea behind Servlet Async I/O and the final goal of implementing NIO Web apps as well.

The holy grail here is to reach a point in which the threads in your thread pool are never blocked waiting for some I/O to happen. They are either doing some CPU bound work, or they're back in the thread pool where they can be used by some other client. When you do I/O you don't introduce wait, you register some form of callback that will be used to tell you when the results are ready, and in the meantime you can use your valuable CPU cores to work on something else. If you think it over, a Callable, a CompletableFuture or a ListenableFuture are that sort of callback objects that Spring infrastructure is using under the hood to invoke their functionality to attend a request in a separate thread.

This increases your throughput, since you can attend more clients concurrently, simply by optimizing the use of your valuable CPU resources, particularly if you do it in a NIO way, since as you can imagine, just moving the request to another thread, although beneficial (since you free a valuable Tomcat thread), would still be blocking and therefore, you'd be just moving your problem to another thread pool.

I believe this fundamental principle is also behind a good part of the work that the Spring team is currently doing in [Project Reactor](https://projectreactor.io) since in order to leverage the power of this type of features you need to introduce asynchronous programming in your APIs and that is hard to do.

That's also the reason for the proliferation of frameworks like [Netty](http://netty.io), [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava), [Reactive Streams Initiative](http://www.reactive-streams.org) and the [Project Reactor](https://projectreactor.io). They all are seeking to promote this type of optimization and programming model.

There is also an interesting movement of new frameworks that leverage this powerful features and are trying to compete with or even complement Spring yet limited functionality in that area. I'm talking of interesting projects like [Vert.x](http://vertx.io) and [Ratpack](https://ratpack.io) and now that we're at it, this feature is one of the major selling points of [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) as well.

Comment: Thanks. You wrote "just moving the request to another thread would still be blocking and therefore, you'd be just moving your problem to another thread pool". So what it is the alternative? Eventually some thread should do this work.

Comment: @KernelMode Compare it to how your hardware architecture works. Your processor is way faster than your hard drive, when you want to read a file, the OS registers a interruption to be notified when data is available in the disk buffer, and in the mean time, it goes and do something else. The CPU is always busy. When the disk buffer has data available an interruption is generated and the OS then can dedicate some CPU for it. So, there was never a thread waiting. That's the same principle in NIO. The code never blocks a thread. When there's work to do, a thread will be assigned to do it.